# Dockerfiles not found when running docker-compose on windows (boot2docker)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

I'm hoping that I've just missed something terribly obvious, but here's the situation I'm faced with.

### Problem

- Running docker-compose on windows after following docker-compose install steps from the website
- docker-compose.yml file works fine on unix systems (have tested on Mac)
- Currently fails immediately **on Windows** when it cannot locate any Dockerfiles for the services defined in the yml file. Here's the error:

[image: The error message]

**NOTE:** The image above might be a bit confusing. The environment variable below is called GOPATH, but the folder on my colleague's computer is also called GOPATH. This gives the impression that the env var isn't set correctly, but it is indeed.

```
version: '3'
services:
  renopost:
    depends_on:
      - reno-cassandra
      - reno-kafka
      - reno-consul
    build:
      context: ${GOPATH}/src/renopost
      dockerfile: ${GOPATH}/src/renopost/docker/dev/Dockerfile
    container_name: renopost
    image: renopost
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ${GOPATH}/src/renopost:/go/src/renopost
```

Above is a snippet of the docker-compose.yml file that is being run. The GOPATH env variable is indeed set and when following the directory path listed, I can confirm the file exists in that location.

Is there some interaction here with the OracleBoxVM that boot2docker uses where it isn't actually finding that file?

Comment: Try to add an env_files with GOPATH value to your docker-compose file.

Comment: Sorry, the image is a bit confusing. The ENV var is GOPATH, but the folder is also called GOPATH. The env var is resolving correctly